# How can I break this long text?

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of code:

```
<ul>
 <li> Something <span> Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Text </span></li>
 <li> Something <span> Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Text </span></li>
</ul>
```

And the css:

```
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin:0;
 width: 340px;
}

ul li {
 padding: 16px 0 16px 0; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

ul li span {
 display: inline;
 float:right;
}
```

The problem is if the text inside `span` is too long, it will push down and break the layout. How can i make the `span` text have its own width and break into rows when it exceeds its own width without breaking the layout ?

Comment: Do you have a more real example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to break words you can use:

```
li {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

But if you have trouble with text next to e.g. an icon which you want to look like:

```
[Icon] My Long Text Is Here
       Which needs to be like so
       if there is long lines
```

And not:

```
[Icon] My Long Text Is Here
Which needs to be like so if
there is long lines
```

You can do:

```
div.icon { float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
div.text { overflow: hidden; }
```

With this markup:

```
<div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="icon">Icon</div>
    <div class="text">My Long Text Is Here Which needs to be like so if there is long lines</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will get you the best browser compatibility:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

`overflow-wrap: break-word` will add a break between characters if there is no good place to split the text.  `word-wrap: break-word` is used for IE and Firefox

Your CSS can be modified as follows:

```
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 width: 340px;
}

ul li {
 padding: 16px 0 16px 0; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

ul li span {
 word-wrap: break-word;
 overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Here's a fiddle with a more contrived example: http://jsfiddle.net/ojaemd8n/4/

Comment: Thanks, but how can I have the border bottom line also pushed down below the whole text ?

Comment: The float:right was causing the problem. When you float an element, it ceases to have height, and its parent element collapses. The two ways to handle this is explicitly state a height or use a clearfix on the <li> element. There's no need for the float in this case, so it seemed more appropriate to remove it. I've updated my original response, and linked to an updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Change your span rule to this

```
ul li span {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:midle;
width:120px; /*Specify the width of block*/
word-break: break-word;
}
```